# Playing videos continuously using HTML5 and JS

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am creating the website using Bootstrap and one of my pages contain many videos and I want the videos to play continuously one after the other.

```
 I used the code in the link below to play the videos continuously:
```

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-play-multiple-videos-in-a-loop-using-HTML5-and-JavaScript-1799.php

```
But in the code above is not working, as in only the first video plays and then it stops.
```

If any one can please help me regarding this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Try providing a fiddle.

Comment: Do you have any error message thrown in your js console? (like e.g `NaN` or `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`)